# Angular 2 feature module lazy loading but not rendering template

Tags: angular, typescript, module

I'm probably missing something fairly simple here, but I can't spot it.

From what I can see, my feature module is lazy loading successfully (in dev tools it only pulls in the files when the required link is selected). I've put break points in the code and can see it is hitting the template inside timesheet.component, but it is not rendering it, leaving me with a blank page (aside from the navbar component, which renders).

The files that get loaded are

1:

```
// timesheet.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { timesheetRoutes } from './timesheet.routes'
import { TimesheetComponent } from './timesheet.component'

@NgModule({
imports: [ CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(timesheetRoutes) ],
declarations: [ TimesheetComponent ],
providers: [ ]
})
export class TimesheetModule
```

2:

```
// timesheet.routes.ts
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { TimesheetComponent } from './timesheet.component'

export const timesheetRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'timesheet', component: TimesheetComponent }
]
```

3:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
template: `<h1>Mobile Timesheet</h1>`
})

export class TimesheetComponent  {
}
```

My routes are as follows:

```
// routes.ts

import { CaseListComponent } from './cases/case-list.component';
import { CaseDetailComponent } from './cases/case-details/case-details.component';

import { Routes } from '@angular/router'

import { CaseListResolverService } from './cases/case-list-resolver.service';

export const appRoutes:Routes = 
[
{ path: 'cases', component: CaseListComponent, resolve:
{cases:CaseListResolverService} },
{ path: 'cases/:irn', component: CaseDetailComponent },
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/cases', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'timesheet', loadChildren: 
'app/timesheet/timesheet.module#TimesheetModule' }
]
```

App.component is bootstrapped, and calls the following:

```
<nav-bar></nav-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

nav-bar contains a routerLink as follows:
    `<a [routerLink]="['timesheet']">Time Sheet</a>`

Comment: where is the selector  for timesheetComponent

Comment: Routed components do not need selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `timesheet.routes.ts` you need to specify the route for the empty path.

For the current configuration, the TimesheetComponent is only going to be invoked for `timesheet/timesheet` route.

As whatever specified in the module specific route is the children of the route specified in the `appRoutes` of `routes.ts`

Change it to the below:

```
export const timesheetRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: TimesheetComponent }
]
```